# Excel copy data from one sheet to another on worksheet refresh with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to copy data from 'Sheet1' in a specific cell to the next available empty cell in 'Sheet2' such that changes (F9) result in data being copied from Sheet1 and a columne of data being populated in Sheet2.

So far I have the below, which throws an error around: `(.Rows.Count`

Is it possible to popluate a column in Sheet2 every time the workbook is refreshed on 'F9'?

```
'In this example I am Copying the Data from Sheet1 (Source) to Sheet2              (Destination)
Private Sub worksheet_calculate()
'Method 2
'Copy the data
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'Select the target range
Sheet2.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: try the code in my answer below, let me know if it works as you intended

Answer (score 0):

You chose last used row incorrectly. Try this:

```
Private Sub worksheet_calculate()
Dim lstrow As Integer
'Method 2
'Copy the data
Sheets(1).Range("I1").Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets(2).Activate
'Select the target range
lstrow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Cells(lstrow + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it will copy Cell I1 from "Sheet1" to next available row in Column A in "Sheet 2".

It's better if you avoid using `Activate` and `ActiveSheet`, instead you can just **Copy>Paste** in one line (as in the code below)

Not sure why you want this code in the `worksheet_calculate` event.

```
'In this example I am Copying the Data from Sheet1 (Source) to Sheet2 (Destination)

Private Sub worksheet_calculate()

Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' find last row in Sheet 2
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Copy the data and Paste in Sheet 2 (+1 for next avaialble row)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & LastRow + 1)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

---

### Edit 1:

Modifed code according to PO updated information:

In order to avoid the `F9` infinite loop, use the `Application.EnableEvents = False` inside your `Sub`.

```
Private Sub worksheet_calculate()

'In this example I am Copying the Data from Sheet1 (Source) to Sheet2 (Destination)
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' find last row in Sheet 2
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row              
    ' copy the values only from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2"
    .Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").Value
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False    
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

You can do the `Copy>Paste` in one line like @user3598756 wrote:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
   .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks - getting there with this. 2 Issues: 1) This copies the formula in "I1", not the value. Could I paste the value? 2) In this case, this causes an an infinite loop on "F9". Is there a way to 'end' after a single press of F9 / a single value has been printed to sheet 2? Thank you

Comment: @StevenBooth try now the modified code (under **Edit 1**)

Comment: @StevenBooth have you tested the modifed code under `Edit` ? is it working for you ?

Comment: Sorry, no - getting nothing pasted at all with the Edit 1 code.

Comment: @StevenBooth unless you moved your data I don't see how it's not working for you as well. Can you upload a screen-shot of your worksheet ? maybe it will help me understand why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Should you be interested in pasting values only

```
Private Sub worksheet_calculate()
   With Worksheets("Sheet2")
       .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @StevenBooth, did you get through it?